# How do I apply animations for previously selected Item

Tags: html, css, animation, radio-button

I have a radio button and able to get the action/ animations on button click.
And how I add an animation for the previously selected Item from the radio button group.

Code is given blow,

```js
function radiobtn_clicked(radiobtn){
console.log(radiobtn.value)
}
```

```css
.toggle-triple-switch label {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 30px;
        width: 50px;
        position: relative;
        border: 2px solid;
        justify-content: center;
       
    }

    
.toggle-triple-switch .toggle-triple-switch__input:checked + .toggle-triple-switch__label{

       color: #FFFFFF;
       background-color: green;
       transform: scale(1);
    }
```

```html
    <div class="toggle-triple-switch" id="time-selector" dir="auto">

    <input type="radio" id="time-now"class="toggle-triple-switch__input" name="time-select" value="now"
        checked onclick="radiobtn_clicked(this)"/>
       <label for="time-now" class="toggle-triple-switch__label" id="now-label"></label>
        
    <input type="radio" id="time-yesrtay"  class="toggle-triple-switch__input" name="time-select" value="yesterday" 
    checked onclick="radiobtn_clicked(this)"/>
    <label for="time-yesrtay" class="toggle-triple-switch__label" id="ysterday-label"></label>
       
    <input type="radio" id="time-tomorrow" class="toggle-triple-switch__input" name="time-select" value="tomorrow" 
    checked onclick="radiobtn_clicked(this)"/>
    <label for="time-tomorrow" class="toggle-triple-switch__label" id="tomorrow-label"></label>
    
</div>
```

[Sample code in Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/so6wb3ft/53/)

Comment: to do so You can use js to toggle classname,


`var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");

if (element.classList) {
  element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
} else {
  
  var classes = element.className.split(" ");
  var i = classes.indexOf("mystyle");

  if (i >= 0)
    classes.splice(i, 1);
  else
    classes.push("mystyle");
    element.className = classes.join(" ");
}`

Comment: @Prabeshgauli: How can I identify the previously selected Item?

Comment: you can give id's to the element and check onclick event. or you can use classname and toggle with js.

Comment: My radio button group having 3 buttons - so If I check whether it is selected or not, will get other 2 buttons. The expected result should be previously selected one.

Comment: you can use to classname on two ids: 
classname1: presentselected
classname2:PreviouslySelected

https://www.instagram.com/

Inspect and check how image is changing on the Instagram login page, You will know it